# Java : Generics and TypeCasting

Tags: java

I am developing a security program I am facing a big problem about generics.

**Consider the following code :**

```
abstract class Dictionary{
    List<Entity> list;
    public Dictionary(List<Entity> list){
        this.list = list; // Error
    }
 }
```

Entity is a user defined `interface` and It has two implementing `classes`:

```
interface Entity{
...
}

class BinaryEntity implements Entity{

}
class ListEntity implements Entity{

}
```

The problem raises in use of inheritance.I have a `concrete class` called binary dictionary which extends `abstract class` dictionary.it contains a list of binary entity the problem is when i want to pass the list to `super class` `constructor` there is a error I know the following statement is wrong :

```
ArrayList<BinaryEntity> a;
List<Entity> b = a;\\erro
```

I have tried upper and lower bounding but still in trouble help please.

*Sorry for the long question.* Thanks in advance

Comment: `List<? extends Entity> b = a;` should work fine. But you will have reduced operations on `b`.

Comment: include the error

Comment: @Codebender doing so makes my list read only I need to put new elements to my list.

Comment: That's why I said you will have reduced operations. You cannot assign a `List<BinaryEntity>` to `List<Entity>` and then attempt to add a `ListEntity` object into it.

Comment: So there is no way!!!???

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make `Dictionary` generic as well, e.g.:

```
abstract class Dictionary<E extends Entity> {
    List<E> list;
    public Dictionary(List<E> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}

class BinaryDictionary extends Dictionary<BinaryEntity> {
    public BinaryDictionary(List<BinaryEntity> list) {
        super(list);
    }
    // ... custom methods
}
```

Comment: super(new ArrayList<>(binaryEntitty));

Comment: @Aidin_t That works too, as long as your subclass doesn't expect to retrieve `BinaryEntity`s from said list.